# ArcGIS JS API - Conditional logic within popup

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have created a custom popup with the popupTemplate function with ArcGIS JS API 4.x

It would be great to introduce some conditional logic into my popups. For example, I am currently displaying a hyperlink to a website driven by an attribute within my layer. Not all features have associated websites, so ideally the conditional logic would only display text if the URL attribute was populated. The code below shows i) my existing popup and ii) how I am guessing I would insert a conditional value.

```
var template = {
content: [

{
  type: "text", // TextContentElement
  text: "<h1><font color='#c94600'>Click <a href={URL} target='_blank'><b>here</b></a> for video </font></h1>"
},
{
  type: "text", // TextContentElement
  text: conditionalFunction
},        

]};
```

where conditionalFunction = something to the effect of...

```
if URL.attribute not null:
   > return URL
else:
   > return null
```

Can this be done easily with simple/basic Javascript??  (i'm very much a beginner)? If I can get this working, the next step would be to show a conditional table :)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways to do this, you can use functions or promises. Basically instead of defining the content in a "static" manner, you do it "dynamic". In this way each time the popup display the content will be generated using the feature data.

Take a look at this [example of ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popuptemplate-function/index.html). It uses function to set the content of the template, and it dinamically define the arrow style to display (up or down and color).

You can do something similar, like this,

```
var template = {
    content: function(feature) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        if (feature.graphic.attributes.URL) {
            div.innerHTML = 
                "<h1><font color='#c94600'>Click <a href=" + 
                feature.graphic.attributes.URL +
                " target='_blank'><b>here</b></a> for video </font></h1>";
        }
        return div;
    },
    outFields: ["URL"]
};
```

I am assuming that `URL` is the attribute that contains the url.